# why when creating a hash do you convert text to byte

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography

Can anyone please explain why 99% of the time when creating a hash, you convert the data into a byte[]. I have been looking for an answer to this question, but all the websites I have viewed just explain how  to create the hash.

I have seen sites using a stream or chars, but 99% of examples convert to byte[].

Sorry if this seems like a newbie question, but I am a newbie and I'm curious as to the reason why to help me better understand the reason.

Thanks

George

Comment: Do you mean why is the input a byte array, or why is the output a byte array? Or both?

Comment: Hi Syon, input converted to byte[]

Comment: Personally I always go back to the source, e.g. type in SHA-1 specification in your favorite search engine and you will immediately be directed to the NIST standard. You will find that it is specified for bits and/or bytes. This also goes for all symmetric block ciphers and asymmetric ciphers, key derivation functions etc. etc. Basically all modern crypto operates on bytes. So be wary of any input/output that is *not* specified in bytes; hopefully the API specifies what kind of encoding/decoding is used.

Comment: Hi owlstead, thanks for the info, hopefully the following link is the site you mean http://www.itl.nist.gov/fipspubs/fip180-1.htm i'm about to read through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash functions operate on byte streams (or arrays). This is just how they are defined.

Text however is in most cases Unicode and thus needs to be transformed into a particular UTF first before you have a byte representation you can work with.

Comment: Text is not Unicode. Text is encoded to bytes using a character encoding such as UTF-8. I might add that an API that claims to hash a string will very likely encode the string to bytes using UTF-8 under the hood.

Comment: I'd argue the same as Python does: There is a semantic difference between text (characters) and data (bytes) and you should never mix them.

Comment: That's correct – text and bytes have nothing to do with each other. The relationship between them is a character encoding such as UTF-8. The "text is Unicode" part is a bit vague. Did you mean that text can contain characters that cannot be represented in ASCII?

Comment: Hi thanks everyone for the answers, its has helped me understand a lot better

Comment: I meant that for the vast majority of purposes text should be in Unicode, which means that there is no *direct* byte-level representation at first (in contrast to ASCII where often no difference is made between a character and a byte). So convert first to UTF-(8|16|32) and then run your hash function over that because hash functions operate on bytes and Unicode text has an ambiguous in-memory byte representation.